# how to select multiple items as default in as3 list component

Tags: actionscript-3, list

I set my list to allow multiple selection. But when I load data in my list, I want to set a few items as selected. Normally you can set only one item selected by using list.selectedIndex. It only accepts int. How can I set multiple items as selected?

Comment: I'd suggest reading Actionscript documentation. You'll see that selectedIndices is coming right after selectedIndex. Documentation can help you as well as inspire you on what else you can do with AS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or even selectedIndices, passing it an array.

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much ToddBFisher. That was what I'm looking for. I tried to vote up but it doesn't allow me to vote up till I have 15 reputation

Comment: Thanks again ToddBFisher. Finally I got my priviliges to rate up. And rate this answer up. Also I didn't know that I could mark and after I read your comment I directly marked your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [selectedItems](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#selectedItems) array of the List.

Comment: It's not working. As I read around, selectedItems is only readable. am I missing something?